# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, authentication

How to reset or delete or enter new password or see the password. If still unable to resolve, how to delete all MySQL dependency and reinstall fresh. I am new to Linux and this is my personal computer (laptop). Please see the output of my terminal.

```
pra@pra-K55N:~$ sudo mysql
[sudo] password for pra: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
pra@pra-K55N:~$ sudo mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
pra@pra-K55N:~$ sudo service mysql stop
pra@pra-K55N:~$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 2466
pra@pra-K55N:~$ 2019-11-15T14:56:08.897357Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2019-11-15T14:56:08.907624Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2019-11-15T14:56:08.915473Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
pra@pra-K55N:~$ sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
pra@pra-K55N:~$ sudo service mysql start
pra@pra-K55N:~$ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
pra@pra-K55N:~$
```

please see mysql.cnf

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

Comment: `cat /var/log/mysqld.log | grep password`

Comment: I finally solved the issue after a week long trying.  thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

*i suggest steps to reset root password by running the server with option --skip-grant-tables this option allow you to log in in mysql without password running this with sudo:*

`# sudo service mysql stop`

`# sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

`# sudo mysql -u root`

`mysql> use mysql;`

`mysql> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("YOUR-NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';`

`mysql> flush privileges;`

`mysql> quit`

`# sudo service mysql stop`

`# sudo service mysql start`

`# sudo mysql -u root -p`

*Now you can login to sql with your new password*

`check may be it's possible to find a query file about root password in path /home/$USER/.mysql_history or /root/.mysql_history`

`Note: prior to MySQL 5.7 the column was called password instead of authentication_string. Replace the line above with`

`mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("YOUR-NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';`

*Goodluck*

Comment: Thank you, I am absolutely new to Linux and wanted to install MySQL and workbench to learn "SQL and Linux". I tride the commands and fail to reset. Please see the output i got and can you please suggest what you want me to do.

Comment: pra@pra-K55N:~$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 3392
pra@pra-K55N:~$ 2019-11-15T04:01:46.088082Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2019-11-15T04:01:46.096591Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2019-11-15T04:01:46.103266Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
pra@pra-K55N:~$ sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: can you post mysql.cnf

Comment: i don't know where to locate mysql.cnf on my files and i will try and send it across. I edited my question which might help to assist me.

Comment: !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

Comment: I finally solved the issue after a week long trying.  Thank you